# RTX 2070 and GTX 1660 super in same rig with 1000W Corsair power supply - rig shuts down

Tags: mining-hardware

I just got my computer back from the shop. I have an MSI RTX 2070 and a GTX 1660 Super in my machine. I swapped out the power supply for a 1000W PSU. Whenever I run ethminer for more than 10 minutes my machine shuts down. I had a technician install the parts because my physical handicap makes me susceptible to damaging the hardware.

I set both of the cards fans to 100% in Afterburner, as well as giving both cards maximum power (electricity is free for me so I don't care how much power I use). Still, regardless of my afterburner settings, my machine shuts down.

I'm pretty sure I have the correct drivers. I didn't give the shop my Windows 10 password so I had to download nVidia's drivers myself. What I don't get is I am maxing out the fan and power settings, so I honestly have no idea why my machine shuts down.

When I just browse the web and do basic computer stuff, everything's fine. However, whenever I run ethminer that's where my problem arises. I'm not a gamer, but I have a few installed whenever I do feel like playing computer games, However, I'm too scared to run ethminer or games because I don't want to damage my computer.

I'm still fairly new to crypto mining so forgive me if this sounds stupid. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out guys.

I removed the Plexiglas off my case because I suspected my rig was overheating. No shutdowns so far, looks like I have to investigate water cooling